# How to change Audio Source when multiple Image Targets are detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

In my Vuforia Unity project, when I target an Image Target a sound is played. I want now to play a specific other sound if 2 targets are detected and another if 3 are detected.

I managed to list targeted Images by doing so in the ARCamera :

```
void Update () {
    // Get the Vuforia StateManager
    StateManager sm = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager ();

    // Query the StateManager to retrieve the list of
    // currently 'active' trackables 
    //(i.e. the ones currently being tracked by Vuforia)
    IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> activeTrackables = sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours ();

   // Iterate through the list of active trackables
    Debug.Log ("List of trackables currently active (tracked): ");
    foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in activeTrackables) {
        Debug.Log("Trackable: " + tb.TrackableName);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to implement what I want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want now to play a specific other sound if 2 targets are detected
>   and another if 3 are detected.

I can't tell where exactly you are struggling in this but you detect how many  targets with `activeTrackables.Count()` then you play sound with `AudioSource.Play();`. Include using `System.Linq;` at the top to use `IEnumerable.Count()`.

```
private AudioSource otherAudio;
private AudioSource anotherAudio;

void Start()
{
    otherAudio = GameObject.Find("OtherAudio").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    anotherAudio = GameObject.Find("OtherAudio").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update()
{
    // Get the Vuforia StateManager
    StateManager sm = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager();

    // Query the StateManager to retrieve the list of
    // currently 'active' trackables 
    //(i.e. the ones currently being tracked by Vuforia)
    IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> activeTrackables = sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours();

    if (activeTrackables.Count() == 2)
    {
        if (!otherAudio.isPlaying)
        {
            otherAudio.Play();
        }
    }

    else if (activeTrackables.Count() == 3)
    {
        if (!anotherAudio.isPlaying)
        {
            anotherAudio.Play();
        }
    }

    // Iterate through the list of active trackables
    Debug.Log("List of trackables currently active (tracked): ");
    foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in activeTrackables)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trackable: " + tb.TrackableName);
    }
}
```

You can also use one `AudioSource` and just change its `AudioClip` depending on how many targets are detected.

Comment: so i implement this script in the AR Camera ?

Comment: Just replace your Update function with the one in my answer.

Comment: it doesn't play the sound it just plays it 1 milisecond and then stop

Comment: ok so i added the isPlaying variable in the if condition. It works now ! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help you.